# How can I maximize my output through a "blackbox" function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, recreational-mathematics, approximation

Let's say I have 7 independent variables (inputs) and 1 dependent variable (output). I don't know the function that relates the inputs to the output. All I can do is define each variable, and the "blackbox" will spit out an output. As you can imagine, there are infinite amounts of combinations, and I can't enter each combination to find the greatest result. Is there a good method where I can determine the appropriate inputs that will give me the absolute maximum output?

Comment: if you only need a local maximum, then any iterative method should work, with an approximate gradient direction.

Comment: Nelder-Mead is a popular gradient-free optimization algorithm that is pretty simple to implement.

Comment: The question is missing important details: are your input variables continuous? Discrete? Integers? Something else? Is the domain of the function the whole real hyperspace (or complex hyperspace)? Or can you assign bounds to your input variables? Is your black box function quick or expensive to evaluate? There’s many things you haven’t specified.

Comment: Is the output a continuous function of any of the input variables? If not, it's a total crapshoot.

Comment: Basically, some of the variables are discrete (down to the hundredth) ranging from 0 to 300. Others are whole numbers ranging from 1-50. And no the output is probably not a continuous function of the input variables, and if it is, I wouldn't know.